# Hook permissions `type`

Tags: php, hooks, acl

Looking at [hook_civicrm_aclWhereClause](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_aclWhereClause) I see there is a `$type` parameter but there is currently no documentation for this type.

What are the allowed values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the various **types** of permissions to be needed for the users. Allowed values are `CRM_Core_Permission::VIEW`, `CRM_Core_Permission::EDIT`, etc.

See more types of permission here - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/Permission.php#L49-L54